# What does cfr. stand for?

Tags: publications, terminology

In a article I saw this expression:

> ... initial sample (cfr. Härdle et al. (2004))...

What is the meaning of `cfr.` or does it stands for?

Comment: Not to be confused with [CFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Federal_Regulations), the US Code of Federal Regulations.

Comment: Not to be confused with the [Council on Foreign Relations.](https://www.cfr.org/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Cfr* is the abbreviation of the Latin imperative *confer*, which means *compare with*.
The common English abbreviation is [*cf.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cf.)

Your citation can be found in [this document](http://depc05.webs.uvigo.es/reports/12_04.pdf), which is written by a Spanish group. A search of the [*Oxford Spanish Dictionary*](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cf.) yields:

> **cf.**
>
> **1** Abreviatura del imperativo latino confer, 'compara' o 'consulta',
>   que se utiliza en escritos para remitir a un párrafo o libro que
>   contiene información relacionada con el tema tratado.
>
> **Usage**
>
> También se abrevia cfr

The last sentence tells you that in Spanish *cf* is sometimes abbreviated as *cfr*.

Comment: @aeismail Thanks,and let me thank you for the other edits: being a non-native English speaker I appreciate edits that improve my writing. Usually, I use "see" too, but I'm not totally against the usage of expressions coming from different languages (e.g., from Latin, French, Spanish or German): I love expanding my vocabulary in any direction!

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I see what you did there with the e.g.,.

Comment: @StrongBad Funnily enough, as a kid, I was terrible at grammar and writing, with abysmal grades. Now I spend my time correcting student's writings - in Italian and English - and arguing about grammar and usage on the net. It's probably a clear example of the Dunning-Kruger effect or of [contrappasso](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrapasso).